# How to concat two fields in Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have 2 fields first_name and last_name but i need concatenation of these fields as fullname.

My code is below

```
User.where('(users.first_name ILIKE ?) OR (users.last_name ILIKE ?)', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
```

but i need something like

```
User.where('(users.fullname ILIKE ?) OR (users.first_name ILIKE ?) OR (users.last_name ILIKE ?)', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

concatenation in Postgres like in SQLite: `||`

```
(users.first_name || ' ' || users.last_name)

User.where('((users.first_name || ' ' || users.last_name) ILIKE ?) OR (users.first_name ILIKE ?) OR (users.last_name ILIKE ?)', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: I haven't got postgres on my laptop to test it, but I am pretty sure I am right. Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query

Comment: and there was a typo: I was using `LIKE` instead of `ILIKE`

Comment: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:207:in `log'
 /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:493:in `execute'
 /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:983:in `select_raw'
 /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:976:in `select'

Comment: new useful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986405/database-independant-sql-string-concatenation-in-rails

Comment: You need single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Change it to use single quotes and it will work:

```
(users.first_name || ' ' || users.last_name)
```

Instead of:

```
(users.first_name || " " || users.last_name)
```