# Searching AR with a term containing space

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, where-clause

I have this line of code in Rails

```
 @people = User.where("firstname @@ :query or lastname @@ :query", query: @query )
```

This works fine finding a user called Joe Smith if searching for `Joe` or `Smith` seperatly.

How can I change this line to fetch users if searching for `Joe Smith`?

Answer (score 1):

```
@people = User.where("firstname @@ :query OR lastname @@ :query OR ((firstname || " " || lastname) = ?) @@ :query", query: @query )
```

See [How to concat two fields in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695926/how-to-concat-two-fields-in-postgresql)