# How do I concat to a text field in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am storing logs in a text field in mysql right now and I would like to be able to add to the text field rather than writing the entire thing in a query because sometimes this overflows to be exceed the "max packet size"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything in ActiveRecord to support CONCAT. However you can write a custom SQL query that uses CONCAT, like so:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Or you could adjust your mysql settings:

```
 mysqld --max_allowed_packet=16M
```

Or the best solution has been addressed already:
[Database-independent SQL String Concatenation in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986405/)