# SELECT DISTINC LOWER : SUBSTR

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm having difficulties to resolve my request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER (CustomerName), 
  SUBSTR(Customer.PostalCode, 1, 3) +" "+ SUBSTR(Customer.PostalCode,4,6)AS'postal' 
FROM Customer
ORDER BY Customer.CuName
```

I'm having the message : Expected Lexical Element Not Found

This one works perfectly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer.Name, Customer.PostalCode AS'postal' 
FROM Customer
ORDER BY Customer.CuName
```

Is anybody can help?

Comment: Only strange thing i see is that there are no spaces around AS, not sure if it is a problem but at least it would look beter with proper spacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                LOWER (CustomerName), 
                SUBSTR(Customer.PostalCode, 1, 3) + ' ' +   
                SUBSTR(Customer.PostalCode, 4, 6) AS 'postal' 
FROM 
     Customer 
ORDER BY 
      Customer.CuName
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Ozlu. 

This is not working. I'm using Access SQL Direct function.

Answer (score -1):

String concatenation in SQL is `||`, not `+`. Also remember to quote your string literal with single quote `'`, not double quote `"`.

Try to rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER (CustomerName),
                SUBSTR(Customer.PostalCode, 1, 3) || ' ' ||
                  SUBSTR(Customer.PostalCode,4,6) AS 'postal' 
FROM Customer
ORDER BY Customer.CuName
```

Comment: String concatenation is `+` on Microsoft SQL Server. Oracle uses `||`, and the rest I don't know, but `+` can definitely be used for string concatenation *depending on the type of database engine he is using*. Since he is using Access, `||` is wrong.

Comment: FWIW, `||` is SQL'92 standard. Didn't know that [MS SQL does not support it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986405/database-independant-sql-string-concatenation-in-rails) though...