# Concatenate variable and string with Arel on join

Tags: sql, ruby, arel

I try to join two tables using [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) to generate some SQL like this:

```
[...]
INNER JOIN "nodes" ON "nodes"."id" LIKE "jobs"."ancestry" || '%'
[...]
```

to match any *job* that starts with one of the *node* IDs. When I run the plain SQL this works, now I try to build this with Arel:

```
node = Node.arel_table
job = Job.arel_table

node.join(job).on(node[:id].matches("_______%"))
```

Now I can't find anything how to get the right string for `matches`, even if I try:

```
"\"nodes\".\"ancesty\" || %"
```

the full string will be escaped. Is there any way to pass raw SQL the the Arel `matches` method that will not be escaped or any other way to get this working with Arel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral` does the job:

```
node = Node.arel_table
job = Job.arel_table

lit = Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("_______%") 

node.join(job).on(node[:id].matches(lit))
```

Comment: To concatenate strings you can also use the `<<` and `+` methods of the SqlLiteral object. But for use with table data you probably need something llike in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12514997/1547831